# How do WWDC presenters paste text during demos?

Tags: macos, xcode, copy-paste

During demos in the WWDC videos, the presenter will often paste code into Xcode to save having to type it in. How are they pasting each different snippet without switching to another app to copy it?

Comment: Without evident, I can only assume that the presentation is preconfigured and it only looks as if the snippets are pasted in. Perhaps they use Keynote?

Comment: I mean the demos where they switch away from the Keynote slides and go into Xcode running live.

Comment: Without any evidence, I'm assuming other folks behind the scenes are doing the cutting and pasting. With Apple Remote Desktop, it's easy to control a user's session while allowing that user to maintain control themselves. Perhaps a wizard behind a curtain is pasting in code when cued, and that would look as if the code just 'appears' in Xcode. Is the presenter actually pressing some keys to paste the code? If you would, please give a link to a demo which shows this in use. I'm intrigued. I use [ClipboardHistory](http://apple.co/1xUTSI7) which can store many copied items. Perhaps they use that?

Comment: Which [WWDC demos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Worldwide_Developers_Conference) are you referring to? They go back to 1995...

Comment: The specific one that prompted me to ask the question was I saw it a couple of times in the 2012 video "[Introducing Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)". I'm afraid I can't remember the exact time it occurs. I have also seen it quite a few other times, in various WWDC videos.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apple used custom code called "Demo Monkey" whose source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/wooster/DemoMonkey).

Comment: Looks like this is it, thanks! In fact I think I remember very briefly seeing some kind of banana icon in the presenter's dock, which fits with the name Demo Monkey.

Comment: There is no icon in the project, but I could understand removing the artwork before releasing it as open source.

Comment: @jobbogamer did you figure out how to use the Demo Monkey application ? I couldn't figure out from the readme how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom Xcode snippets. Snippets can include from one method to whole program.

Check [this article on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/), for me is one of the best explanations of this that I found.

Comment: It seems like there would be some visible action on-screen if that were the case, such as the autocomplete box appearing, since there doesn't seem to be a way to bind a keyboard shortcut to a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

They could be using an app that binds keyboard shortcuts to multiple clipboards, such as [CopyClip](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/copyclip-clipboard-history/id595191960?mt=12).